# How to store Japanese character in a string and write actual japanese characters on a text file in C#?

Tags: c#, file-io, encoding

I have no idea of encoding. I have searched the internet but the answers are too vague. I basically want to store Japanese characters in the string and write the actual characters to a file. Any ideas?

```
StreamWriter sw_CSV = new StreamWriter("I:\\texto.txt", false, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(932));
sw_CSV.WriteLine("設定,HELLO,設定");
sw_CSV.Close();
```

I have tried this code but it only writes Ý’è,HELLO,Ý’è to the file..

Comment: The file contains exactly what it is supposed to contain when you save it with Shift-JIS (932). You just need to be sure you're using the same encoding when viewing/reading the file, otherwise it will look incorrect (the term for this is [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake]).

Comment: how to change the encoding of the text file when reading/viewing?and do i have to download the japanese font and is it already present in the .txt file?

Comment: Check out the question linked to above. I suspect you don't actually want the encoding you're specifying here, but if you do please elaborate on what you're intend to open the file with - it'll help folks provide better answers if those in the linked question fail you.

Comment: Yeah i know it works on .csv file but i want to display it on a text file..thats why i asked it..